# My App from Page Tab wont load it goes to http://www.facebook.com/common/invalid_request.php#

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-iframe, facebook-page

My Facebook App , on my Canvas loads properly. Both http and https AKA SSL. I then added the app to my Page as a tab. But when I click on the tab, All I get is a Facebook Logo Picture, when I follow the link i.e. Click on the Facebook logo link it brings me to https://www.facebook.com/common/invalid_request.php

I though it might be that the Canvas width size is like 720px, and I lowered my sites width to 520px, the size of pages.

A person in Augest had the same question:
[Facebook Application Error In Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979438/facebook-application-error-in-page)

I programmed a Facebook app, and i need to put in a Facebook page.
The application works great outside the Facebook page (standalone).
But when I try to access the application through the page's tab, Facebook's Logo (which linked to http://www.facebook.com/common/invalid_request.php#) appears instead of the app.
What could be the reason to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A Facebook app can have a different page tab URL configured which should be loaded when the App is loaded on a Page tab - is this set for your app? If so, it may not be set to the URL you were expecting (i.e it's not the same URL as your normal canvas app)
Also, when a page is loaded on a tab, a POST request is sent to your server with a signed_request callback, so your server or code may be expecting only a GET request.

Check these docs for more info:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ - note that the screenshots on this are currently out of date, i'll see if we can get them updated this week

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ shows the method to decode the info which is passed to your app on a page-tab load